# Issue with simple Model/Store using REST proxy.

Tags: rest, sencha-touch-2

I have a pretty simple Model/Store/proxy for a REST interface.  The issue I have is when I load the store (through a GET), the store seems to put the new records on the internal toCreate list -- so when I call a sync(), it attempts to POST the records it just sucked down. I know I'm doing something dumb, but I've simplified this up as much as I can without luck...

Model

```
Ext.define('sld.model.Org', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',



   config: {
        clientIdProperty: '_id',
        fields: [
            { name: '_id',                  type: 'string' },
            { name: 'name',                 type: 'string' },
            { name: 'type',                 type: 'string' },
            { name: 'version',              type: 'string' }
        ]
    }
});
```

And the Store/Proxy:

```
Ext.define('sld.store.Orgs', {
    extend  : 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        model: 'sld.model.Org',
        storeId: 'orgs',

        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3003/orgs',
            useDefaultXhrHeader:false,
            enablePagingParams: false,
            limitParam: false,

            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'orgs'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

As an aside, I also am doing this with Basic Auth -- I don't think this would impact things, but just in case, I'll include that:

```
  setAuthString: function (username, password) {
         authString = 'Basic ' + base64_encode (username + ':' + password);
    },

    setAuthHeader: function(proxy) {
        var header = proxy.getHeaders();
        header.Authorization = authString;
        proxy.setHeaders(header);
    }
```

So, when do a load, and immediately call sync() when it completes, I get back that there are  8 object added and the first POST shows up on my server side (which fails since I haven't implemented that yet).

```
orgsStore.load (function(records, operation, success) {
        if (success) {
            console.log('loaded orgs count = ' + records.length);
            console.log ('does it need a sync?');
            var obj = orgsStore.sync();
            console.log ('sync returned added ' + obj.added.length + ' and updated ' + obj.updated.length);
        } else {
            console.log ('failed to load orgs!');
        }
    }, this);
```

Any ideas of where to chase this would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity if anyone else runs into this problem -- the issue turned out to be that I was using 'clientIdProperty' to identify the unique ID of the record instead of using 'idProperty'.  The latter is what I wanted to identify the unique ID of the property.  The document reference is [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model).

And the [answer](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?260182-Store-after-load-has-new-entires-in-toCreate) over on the Sencha Touch forum: